# AJAX loop for WordPress (posts from different categories)

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress, loops, posts

I try to implement AJAX posts loop for WordPress from [Tuts+](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/)
I want this loop to show under comments form in single post page in three columns (each for another category)

In single.php I have divs (numbers comes from category):

```
<div class="news_posts-6"></div>
<div class="news_posts-3"></div>
<div class="news_posts-2"></div>
```

My ajaxLoop:

```
jQuery(function($){
var page = 1;
var loading = true;
var $window = $(window);
 var cat = [6,3,2];

var load_posts= jQuery.each(cat, function(){


        var $content = $(".news_posts-" + this);

        $.ajax({
            type       : "GET",
            data       : {numPosts: 2, pageNumber: page, cat: this},
            dataType   : "html",
            url        : "http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child-theme/loopHandler.php",
            beforeSend : function(){
                if(page != 1){
                    $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">\
                        <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />\
                        </div>');
                }
            },
            success    : function(data){
                $data = $(data);
                if($data.length){
                    $data.hide();
                    $content.append($data);
                    $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                        $("#temp_load").remove();
                        loading = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#temp_load").remove();
                }
            },
            error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#temp_load").remove();
                alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }
    });


});  

$window.scroll(function() {
    var content_offset = $content.offset();
    console.log(content_offset.top);
    if(!loading && ($window.scrollTop() +
        $window.height()) > ($content.scrollTop() + $content.height() + content_offset.top)) {
            loading = true;
            page++;
            load_posts();
    }
 });     
 load_posts();
});
```

Part of loopHandler.php:

```
$numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
$page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;
$cat = (isset($_GET['cat'])) ? $_GET['cat'] : 0;

echo $numPosts;
echo $page;

query_posts(array(
       'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
       'paged'          => $page,
       'cat'          => $cat
));
```

I tried use simple array containing categories numbers but it doesn't work. Depends on

```
data       : {numPosts: X, pageNumber: page, cat: this},
```

there is X post displaying in each column (same posts from first category).

I guess I need to use JSON, which I tried, but it was total disaster (I don't know how to put it together). I just need to call AJAX for three different arguments.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I see that your URL starts with `http://127.0.0.1:4001/` - is the site hosted on the computer you're loading this page from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are various ways you can go about this.

One way is looping over your categories client side first, and make separate request per category. This is what you are essentially doing in your code. You are iterating over an array of categories and making a request for each.

Another way is to pass that array of categories to your handler. All you need to do is modify your handler to accept an array of integers or categories. Then you can return a JSON object. But this involves a lot more editing and on top of that it does not solve the issue of having different sizes and heights for each section.

Thus, below, I have modified the code a little bit to also keep track of multiple sections. There are just a few small edits we need:

- Each section needs to have a category number, pagination number, content section, and a flag whether its loading or not. Each needs to be stored in a single list for tracking.
- We need to iterate over each category to initialize it.
- We need to iterate over each category on window scroll and check if the next item should be loaded
- We need to make sure that each request relates to the requested category

Start by modifying your divs a little (this is just a matter of preference, i prefer storing metadata like this in an attribute instead of a class):

```
<div class="news_posts" data-category="6"></div>
<div class="news_posts" data-category="3"></div>
<div class="news_posts" data-category="2"></div>
```

Here's a modified JS (please be aware that I changed up some variable and function names):

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $window = $(window);
    var cats = [];
    var contentDivs = $(".news_posts");

    var initializeCats = function(){
        // adds category objects to a list for tracking
        for(var i = 0; i < contentDivs.length; i++){
            var catNum = $(contentDivs[i]).attr("data-category");
            var cat = {
              catNum  : catNum,
              catPage : 1,
              loading : true,
              catDiv  : $(contentDivs[i]);
            };

            cats.push(cat);

            load_post(cat);
        }
    };

    var load_post = function(cat) {
        $.ajax({
            type       : "GET",
            data       : {
                numPosts   : 2, 
                pageNumber : cat.catPage, 
                cat        : cat.catNum
            },
            dataType   : "html",
            url        : "http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child-theme/loopHandler.php",
            beforeSend : function(){
                if(page != 1){
                    // this was a bad idea when i wrote the article originally
                    // never concatenate strings on multiple lines by escaping
                    // the carriage return 
                    // $content.append('<div id="temp_load" style="text-align:center">\
                    //    <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />\
                    //    </div>'); 

                    cat.catDiv.append("<div class='temp_load' style='text-align:center'>" +
                        "<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' />" +
                        "</div>");
                }
            },
            success    : function(data){
                $data = $(data);

                if($data.length){
                    $data.hide();
                    cat.catDiv.append($data);

                    $data.fadeIn(500, function(){
                        cat.catDiv.find(".temp_load").remove();
                        cat.loading = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    cat.catDiv.find(".temp_load").remove();
                }
            },
            error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                cat.catDiv.find(".temp_load").remove();
                alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });  

    var onWindowScroll = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++){
            var cat = cats[i];
            var contentDiv = cat.catDiv;
            var content_offset = contentDiv.offset();                              

            if( !cat.loading && 
                ($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) > 
                (contentDiv.scrollTop() + contentDiv.outerHeight() + content_offset.top)
            ) {
                cat.loading = true;
                cat.catPage++;

                load_post(cat);
            }
        }
    }

    initializeCats();
    $window.scroll(onWindowScroll);     

});
```

The PHP file is pretty much the same, just comment out the `echo $numPosts` line:

```
$numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts']))   ? $_GET['numPosts']   : 0;
$page     = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;
$cat      = (isset($_GET['cat']))        ? $_GET['cat']        : 0;

// echo $numPosts;
echo $page;

query_posts(array(
       'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
       'paged'          => $page,
       'cat'            => $cat
));
```

This is just something quick I whipped up. **I HAVE NOT TESTED IT**. Try it out, watch out for syntax errors, and cross your fingers :). I hope this will work for you and if it does not, we can look into modifying it so that it does.